# Let $A\subset R$ and $sup\{f(x)^2:x\in A\}=M(f^2)$, $inf\{f(x)^2:x\in A\}=m(f^2)$. Show that $M(f^2)=(M(|f|))^2$ and $m(f^2)=(m(|f|))^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $A\subset R$ and $sup\{f(x)^2:x\in A\}=M(f^2)$, $inf\{f(x)^2:x\in A\}=m(f^2)$.

Show that $M(f^2)=(M(|f|))^2$ and $m(f^2)=(m(|f|))^2$.

I'm having difficulty showing the above equalities.

I think I can show one direction as follows. Given any $\epsilon \gt0$, we have $f(x)^2\gt M(f^2)-\epsilon$ for some $x\in A$. But clearly $f(x)^2\le (M(|f|))^2$. Hence we get $M(f^2)\le(M(|f|))^2$. Similarly, $m(f^2)\ge(m(|f|))^2$.

But how can I show the reverse inequality? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't really understand. For a real function you have $f^2(x)=\vert f(x) \vert^2$ for all $x \in A \subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, but $(M(|f|))^2$ is the square of the supremum of $\{|f(x)|:x\in A\}$. And $M(f^2)$ is the supremum of the square of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x)^2 \le M(f^2)$ for all $x\in A$, then $|f(x)| \le \sqrt{M(f^2)}$ for all $x\in A$. Hence $M(|f|) \le \sqrt{M(f^2)}$, or $M(|f|)^2 \le M(f^2)$. By a similar argument, $m(|f|)^2 \ge m(f^2)$.